# How can I implement MS SQL 2014 Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am new to MS SQL 2014 stored procedure. I have a table as shown below. I want to create a stored procedure.
I design my stored procedure but I feel so difficult that I can’t even start. Can anyone help me how can I do that?

I have to send CardNo, CardPassword and the PosSerialNo to SQL store procedure. In return I need to get customer name, surname and the amount.

**SENDING:** CardNo, CardPass, PosSerialNo

**RECEVING:** 
    If Sending.CardPass = CardPasswordTable.Password 
    Do the following:
    If successful I get: CustomerName, CustomerSurname and Amount
    If not I get: “No Data Found”

**MY TABLES:**

1)  CardIssueTable:
**Columns:**
    CardId, CardNo, CustId

2)  CustomerTable:
**Columns:**
        CustId, CustName, CustSurname

3)  PosTable:
**Columns:**
        PosId, PosSerial, PosLocation

4)  PaymentTable:
**Columns:**
        PaymentId, PaymentLoaction, PaymentAmount

5)  CardPasswordTable:
**Columns:**
        PassId, Password

**Edited:**

Here is my Stored Procedure. When I execute I get an error.

**Store Procedure:**

```
    USE [LTKB_Card]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[CardCustomerControl]    Script Date: 2.03.2016 10:03:15 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


/*parameters*/ 
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[CardCustomerControl]( 
    @CardNo varchar(50), 
    @CardPass varchar(10),
    @PosSerialNo varchar(50)
)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE /*internal of sp*/
        @CustName varchar(100),
        @CustId int,
        @CustSurName varchar(100),
        @Amout int,
        @PosId int,
        @PassId int

    SELECT @CustName=CUS.CustomerName, @CustSurName=CUS.CustomerSurname ,@CustId=C.CardCustomer
    FROM CardBASIM C
        INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS CUS ON C.CardCustomer=CUS.CustomerName
        WHERE C.CardNo=@cardNo

    SELECT @PassId=PASID FROM CardPASSLIST C WHERE C.CardPassowrd=@CardPass

    SELECT @Amout=PT.PaymentAmount  
    FROM POS P 
        INNER JOIN PAYMENT PT on P.PosLocation=PT.PAYID
        WHERE P.PosSerial=@PosSerialNo

    if (@CustId is not null and @PassId is not null and @PosId is not null) 
        begin
            select @CustName CustName, @CustSurName CustSurname , @Amout Amount
        end
    else 
        begin
            select 'NoDataFound'
    end
END
```

**Execute Statement:**

```
    USE [LTKB_Card]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[CardCustomerControl]
        @CardNo = N'5852354822730001',
        @CardPass = N'jSCm6xkBpK',
        @PosSerialNo = N'RR-312-001387'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

**Error:**

> Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ElitcardCustomerControl, Line 21
>   The conversion of the varchar value '5852354822730001' overflowed an
>   int column.
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> (1 row(s) affected)

**And here are the relationship of the tables:**

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how all the tables relate and show what you've tried so far.

Comment: In english we call them SPs which is short for "Stored Procedure"  It is a procedure which is stored on the server.  A store procedure is a set of actions done at a retail location.

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Can you write a query that gets the data with the filters needed? From there it is pretty simple to put it in a stored procedure.

Comment: I think this can help you about how to create [stored procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) they are pretty simple to create but also depends on the logic you are trying to encapsulate otherwise you might have performance issues

Comment: Please tell me you aren't really storing credit card numbers and passwords in plain text.

Comment: I update my questions

Comment: The logic is difficult, so I ask a question, there are many parameters that makes me confuse.

Comment: No I am not storing in palin text, I will use SP for web-services. Plus card number and the password is encrypted. This is the example. Plus I have another 2 security option in place. Pin code and OTP (one time password)

Comment: The error is because you're accepting an `nvarchar` as your input parameter and apparently your destination datatype is an `int` which can't accept the value you've given it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I truly hope you **do not store password in plain text**, and I don't get all relations between your tables (for example where is relation between postable and paymenttable, between passwordtable and cartable), but I give you an **example** of SP you needed. Don't forget IT'S JUST EXAMPLE.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spnamegoeshere
@CardNo int, 
@CardPass nvarchar(8), 
@PosSerialNo nvarchar(8)
AS
BEGIN
--Check if password is Sending.CardPass = CardPasswordTable.Password
IF (SELECT ISNULL(PassId,0) FROM CardPasswordTable WHERE Password = @CardPass) != 0
BEGIN
-- If successful you get: CustomerName,
-- CustomerSurname and Amount 
-- not sure of table relations
SELECT ct.CustomerName, ct.CustomerSurname, pat.PaymentAmount
FROM CardIssueTable cit
INNER JOIN CustomerTable ct ON cit.CustId = Ct.CustId
LEFT JOIN PosTable pt ON pt.PosSerial = @PosSerialNo
LEFT JOIN PaymentTable pat ON pt.PosLocation = pat.PaymentLoaction
WHERE CardNo = @CardNo
END
ELSE
BEGIN
--If not you get: “No Data Found”
SELECT 'No Data Found'
END
END
```

Comment: In `CardBASIM` what is a datatype of `CardNo` field? Could you please add a sampe of data from  this column.

Comment: I include the picture that shows the data type. CardNo data type is nvarchar(16)

Comment: Make `@CardNo` the same type, and check SP.

Comment: I have to re formulate my picture. You are right. I will update my questions, bear with me.

Comment: I update my picture that shows the relationship of the tables.

Comment: Well, I meant to make `@CardNo` variable and `CardNo` field `nvarchar(16)`. `int` is to small for 16 digit number, if you need to store it as number than use `bigint`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105103/discussion-between-gofr1-and-ntms).

Comment: No I update the picture. CardNo is nvarchar(16) and use PK Id from CardNoList to CardBasım which is FK id.

Comment: Also sending parameters of the CardNo is string type

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the data model this line

```
 INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS CUS ON C.CardCustomer=CUS.CustomerName
```

Is joining a string to an integer.  I can't look at the data to see if this is the exact problem but according to **your model** the join you want is this:

```
 INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS CUS ON C.CardCustomer=CUS.CUSTID
```

This is a standard relationship -- I've no idea why you felt the Customer's name was the field to join to.